# JSON to Java gives errors

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse this following JSON string to java.

```
{"Stdout":"Hello World\nThis is Sara","Stderr":"exit status 124"}
```

This string is dynamic and the content can be different as in,

```
{"Stdout":"Hello World\nThis is Sara","Stderr":""}
```

or

```
{"Stdout":"","Stderr":"exit status 124"}
```

I'm using the [following tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/) and instead of the file I'm adding my String in it.

So I created this code to simply print what `"Stdout"` and `"Stderr"` have to say:

```
public void parsed(String str) {
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(str);
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        JSONArray out = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Stdout");
        Iterator<String> iterator = out.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }
        // loop array
        JSONArray err = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Stderr");
        Iterator<String> iterator2 = err.iterator();
        while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator2.next());
        }

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following result. And I have tried each and every possible solution that I found on Stack Overflow and other sites.

`java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray`

Comment: Why do you convert `stdout` and `stderr` content to `JSONArray`? Values of which are `String`.

Comment: It's in the tutorial that way. @asgs

Comment: @asgs plus I guess it's because they can contain multiple values.

Comment: That's because the author has an array value for the key `messages`. This is what happens if you copy off something and try to use it without understanding.

Comment: I actually agree to what you say. I did copy it off because I couldn't understand it. And you helped me. Thank you. @asgs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversions of `stdout` and `stderr` are wrong. They're both a `String` instead of a `JSONArray`. Try this:

Change: `JSONArray out = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Stdout");`

To: `String stdout= (String) jsonObject.get("Stdout");`

And print that String and see what happens.